# Are DNS requests resolved using Tor when connecting through SOCKS proxy?

Tags: security, networking

Suppose I set up Firefox or proxychains to connect to Tor network using SOCKS proxy on e.g. port 9050.

Now, will DNS requests be resolved using the Tor network?

I know that Tor works with TCP traffic, but how does it handle UDP packets?

I’m uncertain whether DNS request will stay anonymous, since I’ve read that e.g. torrent clients doesn’t work well with Tor by virtue of various UDP protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOR can handle your DNS requests, but it's up to the application to use TOR to resolve the FQDN in an IP. The TOR Browser, for example, will definitely use TOR to resolve your hostname.

**TOR Remote DNS Lookup**: TOR provides a [remote hostname lookup](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt?id=f9e111ead769d48441d99b52039ef0ccbd3f2c62#n1475) through UDP. For that you have to specify DNSPort settings in torrc and set your systems nameserver to 127.0.0.1. Firefox will use the system's nameserver and therefore the DNS requests are routed through TOR.

> DNSPort [address:]port|auto [isolation flags] If non-zero, open this
>   port to listen for UDP DNS requests, and resolve them anonymously.
>   This port only handles A, AAAA, and PTR requests---it doesn’t handle
>   arbitrary DNS request types. Set the port to "auto" to have Tor pick a
>   port for you. This directive can be specified multiple times to bind
>   to multiple addresses/ports. See SocksPort for an explanation of
>   isolation flags. (Default: 0)

Torrents are not working through the TOR network very well, because most BitTorrent clients require for DHT (distributed hash table)  UDP associate which is not implemented. The mircoUTP protocol is also through UDP. So only torrents with a TCP tracker and a TCP connection to the peers will work very well.

As side-note: DNS protocol is TCP/UDP. Up to 512 bytes the DNS can be resolved through TCP.

Comment: It is correct that Tor only supports TCP right? So only TCP based DNS requests may be resolved using Tor?

Comment: What do you mean by the “TCP server can use UDP to resolve the hostname locally”? What exactly is the Tor server?

Comment: Thank you - so by Tor server you really mean the Tor network (or proxy) I guess. How do you know these details?